# Draw images on canvas locally using Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have an HTML5 app that must be run locally. When I run the app and try to load image on the canvas, on Chrome I get the error message:

> Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been
>   tainted by cross-origin data

Both the HTML document and the images a in the local folder.
This is an app that will be distributed to users so I can't run local server. It has to be run as-is on Chrome...
I have read the answers about this issue but they all relate to CORS and Cross-Orgin policy which are not relevant to local files...

What is the solution for this situation? How can I load image on canvas locally on Chrome?

EDIT:
this is the code the throws the error:

```
var canvas = Matach.createElement(false, "canvas", false, false);           
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

context.save();
context.drawImage(
    item.img.img, 
    -item.img.width / 2, 
    -item.img.height / 2, 
    item.img.width, 
    item.img.height
);

context.restore();

res = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: added the code. It is a part of a bigger app.

Comment: Cross Origin policy _is_ relevant.  It's there to ensure that local image data can't be uploaded to a remote site without explicit user direction.

Comment: But here it is not uploaded to a remote site. It just draws the image on the canvas on the local machine. How can it be done without an error?

Answer (score -1):

In chrome getimagedata has some security issues, So for using this you have to do some turnaround, Check these posts for reference, you will get the solution,

[canvas getImageData doesn't work when running locally on Windows? (security exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069400/canvas-getimagedata-doesnt-work-when-running-locally-on-windows-security-exce)

[Why does HTML Canvas getImageData() not return the exact same values that were just set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309364/why-does-html-canvas-getimagedata-not-return-the-exact-same-values-that-were-j)