# Html 5 FileReader always is error

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to read a image file, but it never succeeds.  The onerror method is always called.  Here is my code.

```
   dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(e)
   {
    var f = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    if(!f.type.match('image.*'))
    {
        return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
    reader.onerror = function(e)
    {
        alert("it failed")
    }
    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);

}, false);
function handleReaderLoad(evt)
{
    alert("it worked")
}
```

This always fails.  Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What browsers are you testing this code in? It looks like at least some of your code is browser dependant...

Comment: Sorry, I am testing in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll probably be seeing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665457/updateusing-filereader-in-chrome).

As a general rule you should look more closely at your errors rather than `alert('failed')` because the error code will give you a better idea of the issue, eg: `alert(e.toString())` or `alert(e.name + ": " + e.message)`