# Canvas.toDataUrl("image/png") is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am drawing an image onto canvas. after that I  do canvas.toDataUrl("image/png"); But it doesn't go fine. Here is the link to jsfiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/QcS4u/34/

Comment: What is not working? What is the code expected to do?

Comment: Got the answer from nneonneo! Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `toDataUrl` after loading an image from another domain into the canvas, as it would open up a security hole (information disclosure from other domains).

See [why is this toDataURL line a security error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279438/why-is-this-todataurl-line-a-security-error).

Comment: @MJQ You also can't draw the image to canvas before it has loaded/been cached.

Comment: Well, no, the image draw actually does work. It's the `toDataUrl` that doesn't, exactly as @MJQ said.

Comment: No, in that case you are using `toDataUrl` before the image is drawn. So `toDataUrl` works but produces a blank canvas image.

Comment: No! I first draw image then do toDataUrl and then again draw image from src of toDataUrl!!!!!

Comment: Now that I have added image to the document, but it is still not getting it in toDataUrl!!!!!!

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, you **cannot** use `toDataUrl` after loading a foreign image into a canvas. You just can't. If you have more questions, open a new question.