# Convert canvas to an image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to convert canvas to an image with JavaScript, When I try to `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`  It gives the following error

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Comment: Look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279438/why-is-this-todataurl-line-a-security-error

Comment: this has nothing to do with query

Comment: In canvas image load from other domain so it gives error, When image not load in canvas it is working fine for me.

Comment: Save image file using php: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131281/5466401

Answer (score 27):

You have the right idea, and it will work in very simple cases such as:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);

var img = new Image();
img.src = can.toDataURL();
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/vgmFN/)

But it becomes problematic if you have "dirtied" your canvas. This is done by drawing images to the canvas that are from a different origin. For instance, if your canvas is hosted at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and you use images from [www.wikipedia.org](http://www.wikipedia.org), then your canvas' origin-clean flag is set to `false` internally.

Once the origin-clean flag is set to `false`, you are no longer allowed to call `toDataURL` or `getImageData`

---

Technically, images are of the same origin if domains, protocols, and ports match.

---

If you are working locally (file://) then any image drawn will set off the flag. This makes debugging annoying, but with Chrome you can start it with the flag  `--allow-file-access-from-files` to allow this.

Comment: +1 for the Chrome flag, I hadn't heard about that but absolutely useful in many cases. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks...!!  Simon, Very simple and descriptive answer  :)

Answer (score -8):

This worked for me

```
//after creating your plot do
var imgData = $('#chart1').jqplotToImageStr({}); // given the div id of your plot, get the img data
var imgElem = $('<img/>').attr('src',imgData); // create an img and add the data to it
$('#imgChart1').append(imgElem);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ //
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question, which does not use jqPlot and asks about an error when trying to stringify image data. Your example does solve the problem because it does not have the conditions necessary to reproduce the issue (namely, cross-domain image resources).