# Get canvas as an image from link

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I have a p5.js canvas on my webpage, I want to get that canvas as an image from the link, just like a raw media file being hosted on a website, such that I can use it as just a normal get
media link, not sure what the technical term is.

Is this possible, or will I have to download the image locally first and just use it from the drive?

Comment: Do a little searching yourself and you will find about a half dozen answers

Comment: This is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301879/14559436 . you can add `canva.style.display = 'none'` at the end of the function to avoid duplicating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this, but you have some options.

**Option 1:** embed your sketch as a `canvas` element, which is what p5.js is designed to do. My gut tells me that this is probably what you should really do.

**Option 2:** save your sketch (or several versions of your sketch) as an image by right-clicking it, and then serve that as a normal image.

**Option 3:** do some kind of server-side rendering of a p5.js canvas, and serve that as an image. This is pretty advanced, but you can google "p5.js server side" for more info. My gut tells me that this is probably **not** what you should really do.

Honestly it sounds like you're trying to use p5.js for something it wasn't meant for. Most places you can embed an image, you can embed a p5.js canvas, so my guess is that you probably want to do that instead. But server-side rendering is the direction I would explore if you're super curious.