# iOS JavaScript Security Error

Tags: javascript, ios, security

Does anybody know what causes this error to appear and how to fix it? I am just trying to figure out what it means, because I've never seen this message before.

[image: JavaScript Error]

EDIT:
The only javascript that is used on the page that isnt used elsewhere on the site is this:

`<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function refreshURL(form) {
        if(form.refresh.value != "0") {
            form.action += ";refresh=" + form.refresh.value;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //--></script>`

Are you not allowed to change the form action attribute?

Comment: There is a lot of javascript being used, but I'm not sure where the error is originating from. Do you know a way to figure out where it's coming from?

Comment: See if it's a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18)

Comment: I looked at it but i dont use any file:// or getimagedata functions (unless cloudflare uses these). Ill take another look at the code and see if any of that is being used.

Comment: So I don't know what to do. Try mapping the error to find its line

Comment: What do you mean "mapping" it? Im not a javascript programmer, i prefer other languages.

Comment: Do you have an online example? It hould help a lot

Comment: Is there code anywhere else that modifies a form's action attribute? I could easily imagine a security policy disallowing that.

Comment: Alright, will try to change that.

Comment: Its actually related to cookies somehow...