# Preventing annoying HTML5 geolocation alerts inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, permissions, geolocation

Whenever an script requests the geolocation using `HTML5`'s geolocation API, the `UIWebView` asks for a permission to use the iOS location services.

This is pretty annoying, specially when you load static `HTML` files, it keeps asking the permission for each file, even if the user already granted this permission for the app itself.

Is there a way to prevent it?

I know that on safari the permission for geolocation is based on the domain and I agree on asking for permission when the request is done for a different domain, but shouldn't the UIWebView have the same geolocation permission as the app when loading static HTML or local files?

Am I doing something wrong?

[image: UIAlertView requesting permission for domain]

Comment: Sounds like you actually wanted to file a bug report at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can always pass the geolocation from your app to the javascript loaded into the WebUIView. Look for 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString' in WebUIView?

Comment: That's exactly the trouble I am trying to avoid. I found out that PhoneGap has an interesting implementation of this approach, where it overrides the HTML5 geolocation api, but that is also an extra work I  was trying to avoid. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

Comment: I hear you. In reality its pretty simple, call a js method is pretty simple, no need really for phonegap.

Comment: I see, but I would have to implement all CoreLocation logic in my app, and do the same to keep compatibility with my Android app, that uses the same HTML/JS, for example

Comment: Have you found a simpler solution yet? I'm having this problem but there seems to be no answer in sight.