# JavaScript can't get past SharedWorker() constructor

Tags: javascript, html, worker

I'm doing some research about the HTML5 Web Worker.
I got the 'normal' worker running nicely, however I can't seem to initialize a SharedWorker. I've tried in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, without any success...
Even when I run an online demo, I get no output.

For example, when I open the following document:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web workers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="log">Log:</p>
        <script>
          alert("alert 1");
          var worker = new SharedWorker("task.js");
          alert("alert 2");
          var log = document.getElementById("log");
          worker.port.addEventListener("message", function(e){
              log.textContent += "\n" + e.data;
          }, false);
          worker.port.start();
          worker.port.postMessage("ping");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

task.js:

```
onconnect = function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    port.postMessage("Hello World");
    port.onmessage = function(e) {
        port.postMessage("pong");
    }
}
```

I added the two alert functions for debugging purposes. "alert 1" is always shown, "alert 2" is never shown, so I think that the crash happens in the SharedWorker constructor (no, it's not due to do my browser pop-up settings).
Any help or advice is very welcome!

Comment: What error message do you get in the console?

Comment: It's probably not relevant, but have you tried the same code with the <script> tag in the head?

Comment: Due to Google Chrome's security restrictions, workers will not run locally (e.g. from file://) in the latest versions of the browser. Instead, they fail silently! To run your app from the file:// scheme, run Chrome with the --allow-file-access-from-files flag set. NOTE: It is not recommended to run your primary browser with this flag set. It should only be used for testing purposes and not regular browsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to robertc's tip about checking the console, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

Google lead me to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18), which basically tells you to run it on a web server (I used wampserver) and this helped in my case. Thanks!