# Filepicker.io SecurityError

Tags: javascript, django, filepicker.io

I took the demo [on github](https://github.com/Filepicker/django-filepicker/tree/master/demo), and ran it on my local server. I can pull up the upload dialog and select a photo, but it keeps throwing a javascript error when i choose upload:

```
Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18
```

Which then freezes the page at a spinning uploading screen. My API key has been entered as well. Any suggestions to get this working would be appreciated.

Comment: What URL are you running from? What do you see in the console and network tab?

Comment: running from localhost, also tried setting ```/etc/hosts``` to redirect a url to 127.0.0.1 and it still yielded the same result.

Comment: and in terms of the network tab, all I see is 200, so all good there. But the console is showing the: [http://pastebin.com/pn2cWe2v](http://pastebin.com/pn2cWe2v)

Answer (score 0):

According to what seems to be the canonical Stack Overflow issue on this topic ([Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 when I try to set a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18-when-i-try-to-set-a-cookie)), it likely has to do with the fact that the window.history.pushState call that the dialog makes is not happy when run via localhost directly.