# CouchDB Update XML Attachement

Tags: post, couchdb, attachment

Ive read at least 5 articles on this but I can't seem to get it. I have an xml file that is already in memory in the browser and I am attempting to update a document from my db, for which I already have the doc id. What is the best way of doing this? Is there support for this built into jquery.couch.js, because I can't seem to find any.

Ive attached some code with hard coded values for the sake of my sanity:

```
var xmlTemp = this.fullscoreApp.MusicXML.document;
$.couch.db("mydb").saveDoc({
     "_id": "67e98623efefe16d27e2177b44000aee",
     "_rev": "4-830aad7c3dc9e1d5004439ed1c9196d3",
     "type":"score",
     "_attachments":xmlTemp
     }, {
     success: function() { 
     console.log("PLZ");
     }
});
```

I get a DOM 18 error...but I'm using a public server. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the client you are using but does the xml document above have the correct members (see inline attachments here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments).

Answer (score 0):

What protocol are you using to open your JavaScript file? Are you running it via a webserver (such as `http://localhost`) or just opening the file (which will show as `file://` in the browser)?

If the latter, the browser will report DOM 18, because `file://` suffers various restrictions not present for pages served by a webserver. More info from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18-when-i-try-to-set-a-cookie).

Comment: I am running it online on a public couch server. Its hosted by iriscouch.