# Javascript SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 while accessing cookies

Tags: javascript, html, webos, securityexception, domexception

Folks,
I am working on WebOS Application for LGTV. In previous version my code was working fine while accessing cookie, but with updated WebOS it is giving me error as following:

[image]

Can anyone help me over it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the output when I try to access cookie in JS Console:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see you are loading the app via file:// for testing.  Cookies don't work for file:// urls.  See this StackOverflow answer:  [Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 when I try to set a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18-when-i-try-to-set-a-cookie)

Comment: I have achieved this by using localStorage instead of cookie.