# Adobe AIR HTMLLoader getting Error with Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, air, facebook-like

I am currently developing an AIR app for desktop and I use HTMLLoader, which is the built-in browser of Adobe AIR.

Every time I load the like button to the HTMLLoader, the console will give me below log

"Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
l at http://www.facebook.com/v2.0/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&ret=async&act=disconnect&hash=AQC_IDCnIpaA724U : 3
 at http://www.facebook.com/v2.0/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&ret=async&act=disconnect&hash=AQC_IDCnIpaA724U : 3"

As there is an error, I cannot configure FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {} to check whether the user liked the object.

Please help if anyone got a trick to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Going by this question: [Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 when I try to set a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18-when-i-try-to-set-a-cookie) it's possible that it's because you're trying on localhost, and not a server - set up a simple local server to see if that makes any change.

Also, the WebKit included with AIR isn't the latest version, nor is it identical to the open source version, so it's possible that it's not supported - Try loading up a page with a Like button already there to see if it's that.