# WKWebView & Swift 3 - set cookie using evaluateJavaScript

Tags: swift, cookies, wkwebview

I have been trying to set a cookie for WKWebView using Swift 3 in order to pass a device token to a server.

The code I've been trying to get working in order to set the cookie is as follows:

```
wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.cookie='access_token=your token';domain='your domain';") { (data, error) -> Void in
    print("data: \(data)")
    print("error2: \(error)")
    wkWebView.reload()
}
```

However, I'm stuck here because this code produces the following error output:

> error2: Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure., WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=undefined, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0})

Comment: Are you using a webserver or local file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705057/2124535) ?

Comment: I am using a webserver, Node.Js serving an Angular app

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577303/2124535 If you need to set the cookie after creating the webview, check the second scenario.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out but its not clear to me what users solution you wan't me to try?

Comment: matt'r response

Comment: Mattrs response would be similar to dooing;         request.setValue("Wolverine", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Men-Header")
(after creating a NSURLMutableRequest) and for me the above line of code has not been working like I would hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting the cookie by injecting a script into WKWebView at runtime, which sets the Firebase device token, which is the string I want to pass to my server, as a local storage item.

The code I've ended up with is as follows;

To set the local storage in WKWebView:

```
let addCookieScript="localStorage.setItem('device', '\(self.tokenFirebase)');\nconsole.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));\nconsole.log(localStorage.getItem('userId'));\n"
let script: WKUserScript = WKUserScript(source: addCookieScript as String, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
```

Adding the script to the WKWebView:

```
userContentController.addUserScript(script)
```

After this it is just a matter of loading the WKWebView as normal, and to monitor the local storage of the session through the Safari Developer Tool

Comment: This saved me loads of time. Thanks a lot!