# Phonegap Database problem - storing images in the database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, mobile-safari, cordova

I am trying to make a very basic inventory application with the option
to include a photo of items in the inventory.  I have everything
working except the photo part...

I have looked at this

http://phonegap.pbworks.com/iPhone%3A-Camera-API

and I can get the camera to work, but do not seem to be able to add
the image to the database -

Here is a bit of the code

The database definitions/creation - simage is where the photo should
go

```
db.transaction(
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries (' +
                'id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ' +
                'date DATE, sitem TEXT, snumber TEXT, ' +
                'scategory TEXT, scost TEXT, simage BLOB);'
            );
        }
    );
```

Here is saving the record (after picture is taken)

```
function insertEntry() {
    var date = sessionStorage.currentDate;
    var snumber = $('#number').val();
    var sitem = $('#item').val();
        var scategory = $('#category').val();
        var scost = $('#cost').val();
        var simage = $('#image').val();
    db.transaction(
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(
                'INSERT INTO entries (date, sitem, snumber, scategory,
scost, simage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);',
                [date, sitem, snumber, scategory, scost, simage],
                function(){
                    refreshEntries();
                    jQT.goBack();
                },
                errorHandler
            );
        }
    );

}
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the image (val() isn't going to work) to Base64 via the toDataUrl function of the Canvas...

See Jesse MacFadyen article on doing this [here](http://www.phonegap.com/2009/09/24/image-caching-with-the-html5-canvas).  One little gotcha, if the image server source is not the same the page source this code is not going to work outside of Phonegap due [to not having an origin-clean flag in the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception), however this does not affect the page when running in Phonegap...

Comment: .. then save it as text of course, instead of BLOB in the database.