# How to use canvas.toDataURL() to get base64 of image in Adobe AIR?

Tags: javascript, air, html5-canvas, base64

Is it possible to use `canvas.toDataURL()` in Adobe AIR?

When I try I get the following error:

> **Error:** SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Comment: explain please, what do you want by this? maybe it will be better to put this canvas inside of some other container, which you'll be able to link?

Comment: load an image, cut a portion of the image and then save the image from the canvas to a file, database or a server

Comment: ok i found out why i get SECURITY_ERR http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements is there a way to resize image locally before sending it to webserver using JS or some sfw library for JS?

Answer (score 4):

Adobe AIR enforces same origin for images used in the canvas API. Once you've used something from another domain in your canvas, you can't get pixel data back out of it. However, you can make use of the Loader class to get the pixel data, and convert it into a canvas ImageData.

For example:

```
function getDataURL(url, callback) {
  var loader = new air.Loader();
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, function(event) {
    var bitmapData = loader.content.bitmapData;

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = bitmapData.width;
    canvas.height = bitmapData.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageData = context.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var dst = imageData.data;
    var src = bitmapData.getPixels(bitmapData.rect);
    src.position = 0;

    var i = 0;
    while (i < dst.length) {
      var alpha = src.readUnsignedByte();
      dst[i++] = src.readUnsignedByte();
      dst[i++] = src.readUnsignedByte();
      dst[i++] = src.readUnsignedByte();
      dst[i++] = alpha;
    }

    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    callback(canvas.toDataURL());
  });
  loader.load(new air.URLRequest(url));
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  getDataURL('http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif', function(dataURL) {
    air.trace(dataURL);
  });
}, false);
```

Comment: I tried this code and I get a TypeError: Value undefined does not allow function calls. ??

Comment: @user899641 This was due to `trace` instead of `air.trace` - I've edited the answer.