# Getting error on canvas.toDataUrl('image/jpeg', 0.2)

Tags: image, html, canvas, export, jpeg

It is said on [HTML Canvas Element Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) page of [Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference), that:

> If the requested type is image/jpeg,
>   then the second argument, if it is
>   between 0.0 and 1.0, is treated as
>   indicating image quality; if the
>   second argument is anything else, the
>   default value for image quality is
>   used. Other arguments are ignored.

But on practice I get: **Security error" code: "1000.**

Is it something that is not yet supported? Or why it might be happening? Any insightful advice or explanation might be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

I use newest File API to load local image file into memory first, scale it with the canvas and then export - with custom quality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does canvas.toDataURL() throw a security exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception)

Comment: See the duplicate question for the reason you are getting this security error. (If you haven't used `drawImage` and tainted your canvas, then I am wrong.)

Comment: Well... I saw that question too, but I wasn't sure if the case is same. I updated question. What you think?

Comment: But are you actually saying that the second param works for you in other scenarios? toDataUrl() works fine, until I add that second, quality setting.

Comment: @jayarjo Perhaps I am mistaken. To be absolutely clear: you are telling me that `canvas.toDataUrl('image/jpeg')` works (gives you a valid data URL) but `canvas.toDataUrl('image/jpeg',0.2)` throws the security exception? And this is the case even if you don't use any `drawImage()` calls whatsover? If so, it would be helpful if you could a) create a pared-down test example showing this, and b) clarified on what OS/browser/version you are seeting this problem.

Comment: Well... I use drawImage, how do I put image on canvas otherwise? But yes - canvas.toDataUrl('image/jpeg') works just fine. canvas.toDataUrl('image/jpeg',0.2) throws that error. It comes up on Windows and Mac, browser - FF 3.6.13. I can come up with an example, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=564388).

Comment: Nice find. You can also see it failing the test here: http://philip.html5.org/tests/canvas/suite/tests/results.html#toDataURL.jpeg.quality.basic