# Security Error with canvas.toDataURL() and drawImage()

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, html5-canvas

```
<!doctype html>
<canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
<div id="new"></div>
<script>
var div = document.getElementById("new");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
var img = new Image();

img.src = 'http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png';
//img.src = 'local.png';

img.onload = function(){
    //draws the image on the canvas (works)
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,200,200);

    //creates an image from the canvas (works only for local.png)
    var sourceStr = canvas.toDataURL();

    //creates the img-tag and adds it to the div-container
    var newImage = document.createElement("img");
    newImage.src = sourceStr;
    div.appendChild(newImage);
}
</script>
```

This script creates a canvas with the html5-logo. From this canvas I want to create an image, using the "toDataURL()"-method. Here I get a security error.

Firefox says - Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"

Chrome says - Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

If I use the script with an image on the server it works fine. So it think this time it is really a feature and not a bug.
Does anyone has an idea how I can create an image using canvas with out of an image form an other server?
BTW: the error occurs if you run the site as a local file without a webserver.

Comment: Did you find an answer yet? I have the same issue, it even happens with images from the same server. Once any image has been drawn into the canvas, the whole canvas becomes inaccessible.

Answer (score 7):

You are right, this is a security feature, not a bug.

If reading the Image (for instance with `toDataURL` or `getImageData`) would work, you could also read `https://mail.google.com/mail/` from the context of your visitor get his emails or whatever.

Therefore, canvas elements have a *origin-clean* flag, which is set when external images are written to the canvas. In that case, you can no longer read from it.

You can read more about this topic [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#security-with-canvas-elements).

Comment: The link's now broken, but I believe that information can now be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#security-with-canvas-elements).

Answer (score 0):

i believe that the error is an extension to the same origin policy, basically it isnt allowing you to manipulate a resource from another server. although insecure you could build into the server a method of retrieving external resources: myserver.com/?external=url/path/to/img... that would work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Ya thats a feature. As the image is on another server. Check this

[Why does canvas.toDataURL() throw a security exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception)

You can catch these exceptions. But this will be headache to do for other browsers too and also not right for security.

So better solution is download that image on local.And give the image src path to that.