# canvas.toDataURL() causing a security error

Tags: html, apache, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm using HTML5 canvas and the `.toDataURL()` function through [KineticJS's](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/) `.toDataURL()` method. The canvas uses images that my users uploaded to the site, which are stored on a different machine and subdomain `farm1.domain.com`.

**Problem:** When `.toDataURL()` is called, I get the error

```
SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

Is there a way around this? I also get the same problem if the user access the page via `domain.com` and the image is hosted at `www.domain.com`.

**Attempt:**

I added the following lines to `httpd.conf` within virtualhost and restarted the apache service.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.domain.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domain.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://farm1.domain.com"
```

I still get the same error when accessing image hosted on `www.domain.com` from page on `domain.com`! Is there a way around this in KineticJS?

Comment: Possibly a repeat of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344548/security-error-with-canvas-todataurl-and-drawimage?rq=1   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception

Comment: duplicate and was answered, look at the related in right column, and here is the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements)

Comment: I guess the origin-clean flag must be set to true to avoid the error? Can this be done in KineticJS?

Comment: This seems to work in Chrome 45, i'm only having issues in Safari 9

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers to the images you are loading, not to the page which is loading them. For details on this header, and on CORS in general, you may want to read "[CORS isn't just for XHR](http://remysharp.com/2013/01/14/cors-isnt-just-for-xhr/)", which specifically discusses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around this error. Images loaded in a canvas from a different domain will raise this error as currently implemented by every browser. In your case the images should be stored in the same domain and you would not be getting exceptions.

Comment: It's really strange that I cannot store my images in other servers and CDNs especially when the amount of images cannot fit in a single server...

Comment: @Nyxynyx Yes unfortunately it's a security limitation of the canvas element.