# Cannot Export Canvas as Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have single html page on this page I am just trying to download the canvas but getting this

[image], I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133612/securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure-in-canvas-todataurl) but no luck ,also I cannot set CORS policy because there no web framework behind

```
$("#download" ).click(function() {
console.log( "Handler for .click() called." );

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'image.bmp';
link.href = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL();
link.click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are loading this on the file protocol.

Try running it on an http-server, if you haven't got anything set-up, give the npm http-server package a try. Shouldn't take you more than 5 mins to set it up.

just install it globally and then run your folder.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Gjjs ,tried host on ngrok here http://6bf02462.ngrok.io/ but same error

Comment: What if you'd append the anchor element to the DOM before the click action?