# How to upload an image ON THE PAGE with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, browser, canvas, w3c

This is just a conjecture, I'm not sure whether there is an approach.

The core part of this question is how to get the data of the image without 
making another XHR request for it's src.

I have tried canvas before, I created a canvas object and want to `drawImage` with
the DOM reference of the target image, or an `Image` object with src attribute.
But I always got the same error as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception) mentions.

Go back to question, since the image we see has been fetched by the browser and
must be somewhere in the disk or memory, there should be a method to operate
the image file. If really not, please tell me why javascript or browsers
prevent doing this.

Comment: try this http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery.html

Comment: @jolly.exe this is not what I want, I want to upload an existing image on the current page where script runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting the security exception then you cannot upload that image. Period.

Well, you might be able to [enable cors](http://enable-cors.org/) for that image and fix the error.

Otherwise there are [very good reasons](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules) why you aren't allowed to do that.