# canvas to image shows as no image (blank)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on converting a canvas to an image using dataurl. I have the following code that outputs no error in console. Seems to work somewhat, but when i access the dataurl it shows a blank image.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var myImage = context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);        
        var myImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").setAttribute("src", myImg);
    };
    imageObj.src = "http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/5641/3cc67ca1a74049ce99bc92b.png";
};

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
<img id="canvasimg" alt="" src="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you are doing. You are drawing the image when the image loads, but you are converting it to a data url before the image has been drawn! Move that `toDataURL` call and the `setAttribute` call INSIDE the `onload` function.

Comment: I tried that too, but I get same results. I updated code to reflect what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the code you have posted, I get a Security Error raised. Which is to be expected. The canvas has a clean-origin flag, and once that flag is false, you can't pull data out of it.

Here's a more detailed, related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception)

[Documentation linked to in the answer](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl)

Comment: This is it. The *same-origin* policy applies to bitmap data too.