# How can I upload an embedded image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, upload

I'd like to build a simple HTML page that includes JavaScript to perform a form POST with image data that is embedded in the HTML vs a file off disk.

I've looked at this post which would work with regular form data but I'm stumped on the image data.

[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: To be clear: you want to simulate in JavaScript the manual submission of a form that includes a file upload input control (of an image file).  Is that right?

Comment: If you have control over the application that receives the POST, you could send the image data as a large string parameter in the form (for example in Base64 encoding).  But it sounds like you don't have that control, right?

Comment: I do not have control over the server-side coding.

My goal is to perform the upload entirely thru JavaScript so the process is automatic when the HTML page is loaded as the image is not important, but additional data in the URL is. Unfortunately, the image data is necessary on the receiving end.

Comment: Is your JavaScript served from the _same origin_ as the images?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://aloha-editor.org/ with the image editor http://labs.tapo-it.com/aloha/aloha-imageplugin/examples/example.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## ** UPDATE ** Feb. 2014 **

New and improved version available as a jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/CoeJoder/jquery.image.blob

### Usage:

```
$('img').imageBlob().ajax('/upload', {
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { console.log(textStatus); } 
});
```

---

### Requirements

- the [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) element (HTML 5)
- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)
- [XMLHttpRequest.send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#send)(:FormData)
- [Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob#Constructor)
- [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array)
- [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.atob), [escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.escape?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM:window.escape)

Thus the browser requirements are:

- Chrome: 20+
- Firefox: 13+
- Internet Explorer: 10+
- Opera: 12.5+
- Safari: 6+

Note: The images must be of the **same-origin** as your JavaScript, or else the browser security policy will prevent calls to `canvas.toDataURL()` (for more details, see this SO question: [Why does canvas.toDataURL() throw a security exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception)).  A proxy server can be used to circumvent this limitation via response header injection, as described in the answers to that post.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keWkJ/3/) of the below code.  It should throw an error message, because it's not submitting to a real URL ('/some/url').  Use firebug or a similar tool to inspect the request data and verify that the image is serialized as form data (click "Run" after the page loads):

[image: POST data]

### Example Markup

```
<img id="someImage" src="../img/logo.png"/>
```

### The JavaScript

```
(function() {
    // access the raw image data
    var img = document.getElementById('someImage');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var blob = dataUriToBlob(dataUrl);

    // submit as a multipart form, along with any other data
    var form = new FormData();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/some/url', true);    // plug-in desired URL
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                alert('Success: ' + xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                alert('Error submitting image: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
    form.append('param1', 'value1');
    form.append('param2', 'value2');
    form.append('theFile', blob);
    xhr.send(form);

    function dataUriToBlob(dataURI) {
        // serialize the base64/URLEncoded data
        var byteString;
        if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) {
            byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        }
        else {
            byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        }

        // parse the mime type
        var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

        // construct a Blob of the image data
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            array.push(byteString.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        return new Blob(
            [new Uint8Array(array)],
            {type: mimeString}
        );
    }
})();
```

### References

SO: ['Convert DataURI to File and append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

Comment: I used the same above given code but it shows me "ArrayBuffer is deprecated in XMLHttpRequest.send(). Use ArrayBufferView instead." Please help me out.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You must not be using the same code.  I'm using [XMLHttpRequest.send(:FormData)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility). The FormData contains a Blob, and the Blob is constructed using a TypedArray, "Uint8Array" [(which is an ArrayBufferView)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Buffers_and_views.3A_typed_array_architecture).  I'm not using an ArrayBuffer at all.

Comment: Worked great. Too bad that `dataUriToBlob` isn't a part of jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about embedded image data like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML

****If my assumption is incorrect, please ignore this answer.**

You can send it as JSON using XMLHttpRequest. 
Here is sample code: (you may want to remove the header part ('data:image/png;base64,') before sending)

**Image**

```
<img id="myimg" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

**Button**

```
<input id="subbtn" type="button" value="sub" onclick="sendImg()"></input>
```

**Script**

```
function sendImg() {
    var dt = document.getElementById("myimg").src;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/Home/Index', true); //put your URL instead of '/Home/Index'
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { //4 means request finished and response is ready
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    var contentType = "application/json";
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);

    for (var header in this.headers) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
    }

    // here's our data variable that we talked about earlier
    var data = JSON.stringify({ src: dt });

    // finally send the request as binary data
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

***EDIT***

As @JoeCoder suggests, instead of json, you can also use a FormData object and send in Binary format. Check his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12470362/441860) for more details.

Comment: This requires special server-side processing.  Instead, use the FormData object to embed the binary data in a standardized way.