# Get image from url and convert into blob using javascript

Tags: javascript, database, image, google-maps-api-3, blob

Well guys i was looking many hours for internet and i couldn't find the answer.

I have an URL with an image like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false

I need to load this image using ajax or another tool and later convert it into a blob to save in my database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Blit the image into a canvas element, generate a dynamic URI from the canvas, decode the URI into bytes, construct a blob, add to a FormData object, and submit with XMLHttpRequest.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391628/how-can-i-upload-an-embedded-image-with-javascript/12470362#12470362).

PS - because the image is served from Google, you will need to use a proxy to circumvent "same-origin" security policy, as described in my linked post.

Answer (score 1):

That is against the [Terms of Use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

See this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_staticmaps_reuse) which addresses your question.

Comment: Actually it's only "storing and serving" that's against the terms. OP is simply looking to store, which could be a fair use.

Comment: That is only the wording of the FAQ. I believe what I said, that saving it is against the  terms, but [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL).