# Canvas toDataURI() on chrome security issue

Tags: c#, javascript, canvas, svg

I am having an issue with Canvas on chrome. I know that this is mentioned a lot but i was not able to find a solution that suites me.

Basically, i am designing a website that does the following steps:
- Loads an SVG image template from the hosting server into an object. 
- Manipulates that SVG (Coloring, hiding and showing layers etc...)
- Then send the manipulated version to the server to be inserted into a pdf document and emailed.

My issue is with the last step. The approach that i was using involves:
- Fetching the content document of the SVG and serializing its XML.

```
 var s = new XMLSerializer();
 svg = document.getElementById('theSVG').contentDocument;
 var xmlTest = s.serializeToString(svg);
```

- Defining a new image with an onLoad function and applying the src to it:

  drawnImage.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + escape(xmlTest);
- Creating a canvas element and drawing that image into it:

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
  var cont = canvas.getContext('2d');
  cont.drawImage(drawnImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
- The last step is extracting the dataURI from the canvas element as such:

> var ImageDataURl = canvas.toDataURL();

After that, the data (base64) is sent to the server, coonverted to bitmap and saved as a jpeg image on the server disk then inserted as a part of a big pdf document.

All was going well until i tested it out on chrome, and i ran through the security error that states:

> Uncaught SecurityError: An attempt was made to break through the
>   security policy of the user agent

As i read about this error, i knew that this is a chrome security issue for cross domain images and blah blah. What i would like to know is the following:
- Is creating a new canvas and loading the image into it on the user's browser treated as a file from another domain?
- And is there a workaround for this even if it is server side (I am using C#) i do not mind. I tried uploading the SVG XML and tried convert it to base64 string but with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using fabric js. Great library. The code is as follows:

```
var a = document.getElementById("theSVG"); //This is the <object>
a.setAttribute('data', 'worldmap.svg'); //Setting the data attribute to the svg file


a.onload = function () {

    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    var s = new XMLSerializer();
    var xml = s.serializeToString(svgDoc);


    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

    var svg = xml;

    fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function (objects, options) {
        var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        canvas.add(loadedObject);
        canvas.calcOffset();
        canvas.renderAll();
        if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
            alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
        }
        else {
            window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
        }

    });
}
```

This solved the .toDataURL() issue. But i am left with the problems with my SVG File. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome loading an SVG image into a canvas taints the canvas which means that you can't read any data from it although you can still write to it. It seems to have been [fixed recently in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249037) provided you avoid certain SVG elements such as `<foreignObject>` so perhaps it will be in a Chrome release version soon.

In the meantime, perhaps you could use Firefox instead which wouldn't taint the canvas.

Comment: Hey and thanks for replying. If it was up to me i would use firefox. But this has to be a client customizing this SVG, thus i have no control on which browser they use.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am doing like below. I didn't get any error. Hope this help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#exportButton").click(function() { 

    html2canvas( [ document.getElementById("divId_for_Pdf") ], {
       onrendered: function(canvas) {
           var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
         // $('#img1').attr('src',dataUrl);
           var action ='saveChartData';
            var data="dataUrl="+dataUrl;
           $.ajax({url:action, data:data, dataType:'text',type:'POST',cache:false,
               success: function(data) {
                 //alert("success..........!")
                   window.location.href = "${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/adminConfig/downloadAnalyticsChart?tenantName=${tenantInstance?.tenantName}&from=Dashboard"
               },
               error: function(request, status, error) {
                   alert('error');
               },
               complete: function(data){

               }
           });

       }
   });
});        

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try this var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); on chrome?

Comment: This exact code line is what is causing a security issue in chrome. My code works on all browser except on chrome. You obviously have a different version of chrome. I am on 29.0.1547.62 m

Comment: I am also using same version

Answer (score 0):

One cause of the problem is when you use another "domain" for the image...

If you tried toDataUrl from an Url of your domain, it works, otherwise it doesn't.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390361/2735734)

Then I added

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

on my server but that didn't work...

Finally I tried [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CORS_Enabled_Image). I just put a img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; and the header

And that did work.

Comment: Hey, You can check the answer. Access that link and read through the article, there is a library called SVG.toDataURL js. You can download it from [HERE](https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL). Yet i urge you to read the article as well.