# Kinetic JS: toDataURL() doesn't work with Images

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have defined this function:

```
function viewCanvasImg() {
    //("stage" is a kineticjs stage class object)
    stage.toDataURL({ 
        callback: function(dataUrl) {
            document.getElementById('prova').src=dataUrl;
            window.open(dataUrl);
        }
    });
}
```

But when i call it by button it doesn't work. With shapes and draws all works fine but with images on canvas not.

**SOLVED**
I noticed that the code didn't work only on local machine then i put on my webserver and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the tutorial and see if it's working for you there:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/

Your code looks proper. If it's not working you're probably getting a Javascript error before the window.open is called. Check the console and `console.log` is your friend.

Also, what could be happening is `stage` is not defined in your function. So you might need to pass the stage object through the `viewCanvasImg` function.

**Update**

With images and `toDataURL` you have to becareful of the **Same Origin Policy**.

Read here for more information: [Why does canvas.toDataURL() throw a security exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

This is the error KineticJS throws in the console:

> Kinetic warning: Unable to get data URL. An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.

Comment: the function works when my canvas only contains draws or shapes but for my project i need that my canvas contain drag and droppable images and in this case my function doesn't work

Comment: It should work fine, but there is an exception for images. See my updated answer.

Comment: I've solved. The images were already in the same folder of my page. But i noticed that the code didn't work only on local machine then i put on my webserver and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue whilst opening a data image url in a new window; doesn't display on local.

Try right-click > Inspect Element in Chrome.