# Sending a canvas.toDataUrl() to php via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, canvas

I am trying to send a canvas.toDataUrl() to a php page via AJAX.

Here's is my try:

JavaScript code:

```
function showUser() {
str = "url="+canvas.toDataUrl();

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
             // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?"+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

php:

```
<?php
   $url = $_GET['url'];
   echo "$url";
?>
```

The code above doesn't seem to be working, although I did the exact same thing but with a String value instead, like the following:

```
    function showUser() {
str = "url=12345";

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
             // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?"+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This one works fine, 
but when I use canvas.toDataUrl() it doesn't work !? why?

Is there another way to send canvas.toDataUrl() to php?

Thanks

Comment: IE 8- don't support `<canvas>` so you can drop that old browser bit from your code, also, where have you `var`d `xmlhttp` and `str`?

Comment: in an html file in the same folder (I'm not sure I understood the question) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

The problem was that I was trying to send Large data through GET,
I solved it by sending the same (large) data through POST
POST is a little more complex than GET though

Here's how to send data via AJAX using POST:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml

I used the code in the link and it works fine with me
anyone having the same problem please refer the link above and use POST instead of GET

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

I reccommend trying the javascript encodeURIComponent() function like this:

```
str = "url="+encodeURIComponent(canvas.toDataUrl());
```

The thing is, that dataurl contains symbols like "/" so it might get falsely interpreted.
Let me know if that works.

Comment: `/` won't be falsely interpreted after a `?` because you're now in the _search_

Comment: Could you try `console.log(canvas.toDataUrl());` just to check whether anything is coming from there at all. If not, there is probably something wrong with your variable canvas, which is out of scope for this function.

Comment: I just tried it, but i'm not sure what it does. `alert(canvas.toDataUrl())` works fine and outputs an alert box with the url but it is not sent to the php file !
thanks

Comment: I just tried choosing another canvas (i.e. drawing another image in the canvas) and it worked fine !
The problem is that it does not want with a certain image. why!? really strange

Comment: That is indeed very strange. I can't think of any possible reasoning for this from the top of my head. Glad you got it working for at least some image.

Comment: I just realised something. You could check for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception . If the drawing is not based on the same domain, this could raise an error. Seems unlikely though.

Comment: @ReGdYN, actually a CORS security violation **is likely** since the method succeeds on one image and fails on another.