# Useing javascript capture video picture

Tags: javascript

I want capture video picture,and write some code like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#capture").click(function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = $("#video").width();
        canvas.height = $("#video").height();
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage($("#video").get(0), 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        $("#output").prepend(img);
    })
}); 
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<video id="video" controls="controls">  
  <source src="test.mp4" />  
</video>  
<button id="capture">Capture</button>  
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it always have the error:
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

I try to output the canvas, it works.But it can't work by `canvas.toDataURL();`
How do I get image?Thanks.

Comment: Did you try looking up what your error means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2390361/1519836

Comment: I understand! Very thank you for your answer